# Python - add multiple files to folder but run event only once

Tags: python, events, raspberry-pi, event-handling, python-watchdog

I'm trying to make a watchdog to listen to a folder changes (adding/deleting) files.

My problem is, that every time I copy-create/delete **several files** from this folder (and its subfolders), the event chain starts one by one for each and every file.

How can I make the `on_event()` method to be invoked only once, after multiple files creation/deletion?

Let's say I'm copying to this folders two images.

I want the event handler to be invoked only once after file transfer finishes, and **not** twice - once for each image - as it currently works.

Thanks!

The code runs on a raspberry pi 3 with python 3.7.

Here's the code:

```
    import os
    import time
    import psutil
    from watchdog.observers import Observer
    from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
    
    i = 0
    
    
def show_stats():
    global i
    read = "read #" + str(i) + ":"
    mem = "\nmemory in use: " + str(psutil.virtual_memory().percent)+"%"
    cpu = "\ncpu load: " + str(psutil.cpu_percent())+"%"
    temp = "\ncurrent " + \
        os.popen("vcgencmd measure_temp").readline().replace(
            "=", ": ").replace("'C", " C°")
    end = "\n=================="
    i += 1
    stats = read + mem + cpu + temp + end
    return stats
    
    
    class Watcher:
        DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH = r'/home/pi/Desktop/jsSlider/images'
    
        def __init__(self):
            self.observer = Observer()
            print("watching ", self.DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH, "...")
    
        def run(self):
            event_handler = Handler()
            self.observer.schedule(
                event_handler, self.DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH, recursive=True)
            self.observer.start()
            try:
                while True:
                    time.sleep(5)
                    print(show_stats())
            except Exception as e:
                self.observer.stop()
                print(e)
            self.observer.join()
    
    
    class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
        @staticmethod
        def on_event(event):
            wait = 1
            elif event.event_type == 'created' or event.event_type == 'deleted':
                print("Received event - %s. " %event.src_path, str(event.event_type))
                time.sleep(wait) #i found that its best to give some timeout between commands because it overwhelmed the pi for some reason (one second seems to be enough)...
                os.system('python /home/pi/Desktop/Slider/scripts/arr_edit.py') #recreate the JS array
                time.sleep(wait)
                os.system('cp -r /home/pi/Desktop/jsSlider/scripts/imgArr.js /home/pi/Desktop/jsSlider/themes/1') #copy the newly created JS array to its place
                time.sleep(wait)
                os.system('sudo pkill chromium') #"refresh" the page -the kiosk mode reactivates the process...
                # os.system('cls')
                print('done!')
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        w = Watcher()
        w.run()
```

**Edit I**

There is a poor rpi3 connected to a tv in some clinic, working in kiosk mode to display images from a local html file (with some js code - the slide show run with an existing JS script - i can upload everything if requested | the images are also on the pi itself).

What I'm trying to achieve is to automatically:

1. rebulid the JS array (with a working python script - code below (arr_edit.py)).
2. copy the new array to its desired location. (shell command)
3. and restart chromium with "pkill chromium". (shell command)

Now, I cannot allow that every time someone copies/deletes *multiple* images, the commands will run each time - which means:

whenever 2+ images are being added, i cannot "restart" the kiosk
(sudo pkill chromium) each and every time a file is created.

Every time you copy multiple files (images in that case), **for each individual** image that was created in the folder, an entirely individual event.created is invoked, therefore for 5 images, there will be 5 different event.created events that will fire the on_event() method each on its own turn, making the kiosk restart 5 times in a row. (now think of what will happen if a 50 files transfer occurs - the pi will just crash)

Therefore, I need a method to invoke the command only 1 time after file transfer finishes, **regardless** of how many files has changed/created/deleted in the folder.

arr_edit.py (not entirely my code):

```
import os
dir_path = r'/home/pi/Desktop/jsSlider/images'
file_path = r'/home/pi/Desktop/jsSlider/scripts/imgArr.js'

directory = os.fsencode(dir_path)
arr_name = 'images=[\n'
start_str = '{"img":"./images/'
end_str = '"},\n'
images = ''


def writer(array, imagesList):
    str_to_write = array + imagesList + ']'
    f = open(file_path, 'w')
    f.write(str_to_write)
    f.close


file_list = os.listdir(directory)
for file in file_list:
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".jpeg") or filename.endswith(".webp") or filename.endswith(".webp"):
        if file == file_list[len(file_list)-1]:
            end_str = '"}\n'
        images += start_str + filename + end_str
        continue
    else:
        continue

writer(arr_name, images)
```

output JS array (sample from inside imgArr.js):

```
images=[
{"img":"./images/246.jpg"},
{"img":"./images/128.jpg"},
{"img":"./images/238.webp"},
{"img":"./images/198.jpg"},
{"img":"./images/247.webp"}
]
```

Comment: I haven't reviewed the code, but one solution would be to start a timer every time the contents of a directory change. I the contents haven't changed for `x` amount of time then execute your function.

Comment: for my understanding that creates another problem:
every time the timer ends, the function will be executed regardless if folder has changed.
correct me if i didnt understand correctly the idea. thank!

Comment: The timer should only be invoked if the observer detects a change. I haven't used the `watchdog` package but I will dig in and provide a coded solution later tonight if still needed.

Comment: i will try to implement a time
would still like to see another solution

Comment: Taking a step back... what is it, just in simple English,  that you are actually trying to achieve with this mechanism? There may be a simpler, more reliable method.

Comment: making the method on_event(event) work ONLY ONCE even if FileSystemEventHandler catches several events (like if 2+ files were created in the folder). 
i wrote an example of what i mean exactly :)

Comment: Ok, maybe try to take 3 steps back to say what you are trying to do - more along the lines of *"whenever remote server A puts three files in a given directory, I want to delete the second of the three and move the other 2 to a different directory"* rather than worrying about the specifics of event handlers. I am trying to work out the constraints and possibilities so I, or someone else can help you better.

Comment: ill edit the post

Comment: Thank you for the update. So, one idea might be to change your code that uploads/changes the images such that when it is complete and has finished uploading it creates an empty file called `update.txt`. The RasPi check for that file existing and if it does, it does the update of the JS, restarts the kiosk and deletes the file `update.txt` so it doesn't update again till the next upload.

Comment: alright, but how would i know when to delete the file? 
lets say the first file created in the folder initiates the file creation.
how can i know when the file transfer finishes - so i can delete the file and initiate the rest?

ps. file creation is made by simply draggin and dropping the images into a shared folder (using samba on the rpi) 
there is no script/program that do so...

Comment: Ok, how about logging the file creations as you already do, and then not doing anything until all the logged files haven't changed in the last 5 seconds?

Comment: interesting idea, i will try to implement something later today. 
will update.
thanks!

Comment: it ried implementing with no luck. (now the events not even being cought. im cluless at this point haha) 
im adding the code

Comment: Cool - well done! You can add your code as the answer where everyone can see it and accept it as correct and bag the points too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark suggested in the comments,
i added a check to see if the js file has changed in the past 5 minutes.
if the file changed,
wait for another 5 minutes and re-initiate the cange (if more files have been added to the folder) so the new, larger files will also be shown in this run.
Works like a charm!
many thanks!!
here's the final watchdog.py

```
import os
import time
import psutil
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

i = 0


def show_stats():
    global i
    read = "read #" + str(i) + ":"
    mem = "\nmemory in use: " + str(psutil.virtual_memory().percent)+"%"
    cpu = "\ncpu load: " + str(psutil.cpu_percent())+"%"
    temp = "\ncurrent " + \
        os.popen("vcgencmd measure_temp").readline().replace(
            "=", ": ").replace("'C", " C°")
    end = "\n=================="
    i += 1
    stats = read + mem + cpu + temp + end
    return stats


def wait_for_file(file):
    time.sleep(300)
    if age(file) >= 5:
        modify()


def modify():
    os.system('python /home/pi/Desktop/jsSlider/scripts/arr_edit.py')
    os.system(
        'cp -r /home/pi/Desktop/jsSlider/scripts/imgArr.js /home/pi/Desktop/jsSlider/themes/1')
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system('sudo pkill chromium')
    # os.system('cls')
    print("done!\nwatching...")


def age(filename):
    return ((time.time() - os.path.getmtime(filename))//60)


class Watcher:
    DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH = r'/home/pi/Desktop/jsSlider/images'

    def __init__(self):
        self.observer = Observer()
        print("watching ", self.DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH, "...")

    def run(self):
        event_handler = Handler()
        self.observer.schedule(
            event_handler, self.DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(5)
                print(show_stats())
        except Exception as e:
            self.observer.stop()
            print(e)
        self.observer.join()


class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    @ staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event):
        file = r'/home/pi/Desktop/jsSlider/scripts/imgArr.js'
        if event.event_type == 'created' or event.event_type == 'deleted':
            print("Received event - %s. " %
                  event.src_path, str(event.event_type))
            time.sleep(5)
            if age(file) < 5:
                wait_for_file(file)
            else:
                modify()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = Watcher()
    w.run()
```

Comment: Well done. You can accept your own answer too.